# Crear Tablas con nombres dinámicos en SQL Server desde Pyhton

Tags: python, sql-server

Estoy haciendo un pequeño desarrollo en **Python** y **Sql Server**, este desarrollo consiste básicamente en una serie de tablas donde un grupo de usuario cargaran información, se debe chequear que la tabla exista y si no existe se debe crear, y aquí es donde tengo el problema ya que no se como crear la tabla con nombres dinámicos, la única condición es que el nombre de la tabla siempre tendrá la estructura **XXXX_DCR** donde **XXXX** serán letras y sera capturada desde teclado.

Así esta conformada la tabla:

```
def creatabla():
       cursor.execute('''
           CREATE TABLE **tabla_name** (
               "Country Id" FLOAT  ,
               "Country Name" NVARCHAR (255),
               "Auditor Id" FLOAT  ,
               "Resource Name" NVARCHAR (255),
               "SMS Id" FLOAT  ,
               "Period ID" FLOAT  ,
               "Instruction Id" FLOAT  ,
               "Category ID" FLOAT  ,
               "Category Name" NVARCHAR (255),
               "Module Name" NVARCHAR (255),
               "Entity Id" FLOAT  ,
               "Bar Code" FLOAT  ,
               "Product Description" NVARCHAR (255),
               "Fact Id" FLOAT  ,
               "Fact Description" NVARCHAR (255),
               "Fact Attribute Index" FLOAT  ,
               "Fact Observation Name" NVARCHAR (255),
               Value FLOAT  ,
               "Visit  Date" DATETIME  ,
               "Audit Status" NVARCHAR (255),
               "Original Fact Value" FLOAT  ,
               "Cluster Id" FLOAT)
       ''')        

connt=Conectatabla()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes crear una tabla con un nombre dinámico, no al menos desde SQL, pero lo que si puedes es definir dinámicamente la sentencia de creación de la misma.

```
def creatabla():
  SQL = '''
        CREATE TABLE {0} (
            "Country Id" FLOAT  ,
            "Country Name" NVARCHAR (255),
            "Auditor Id" FLOAT  ,
            "Resource Name" NVARCHAR (255),
            "SMS Id" FLOAT  ,
            "Period ID" FLOAT  ,
            "Instruction Id" FLOAT  ,
            "Category ID" FLOAT  ,
            "Category Name" NVARCHAR (255),
            "Module Name" NVARCHAR (255),
            "Entity Id" FLOAT  ,
            "Bar Code" FLOAT  ,
            "Product Description" NVARCHAR (255),
            "Fact Id" FLOAT  ,
            "Fact Description" NVARCHAR (255),
            "Fact Attribute Index" FLOAT  ,
            "Fact Observation Name" NVARCHAR (255),
            Value FLOAT  ,
            "Visit  Date" DATETIME  ,
            "Audit Status" NVARCHAR (255),
            "Original Fact Value" FLOAT  ,
            "Cluster Id" FLOAT)
       '''
  nombre_de_tabla = 'XXXX_DCR' # esta variable la debería completar del ingreso por teclado
  cursor.execute(SQL.format(nombre_de_tabla))
```

Definimos la clausula a ejecutar `SQL` dónde indicamos `{0}` como el lugar dónde irá el nombre de la tabla, luego usamos la función de cadena [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) para configurar el nombre `SQL.format(nombre_de_tabla)`

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la respuesta, ya pude solucionar la creación de las tablas con tus recomendaciones